# multiple angular elements in same page sharing same service with lazy loading

Tags: angular, web-component

I looked in this link https://github.com/angular/angular/tree/master/aio/src/app/custom-elements

for understand if that possible to implement lazy loading of angular elements and have same service shared between them(i mean multiple elements in the same page).

is it possible with the current version of angular ? 
from looking in the source code in the link above i can create angular element with selector attribute(@Input) to load custom elements.
my question is how i implement lazy loading in that case and how  i create the elements to share same service.

Comment: Did you try to do this? What didn't work when you did?

Comment: *if that possible to implement lazy loading of angular elements and have same service shared between them* services are singletons by default.

Comment: @Antoniossss services are not singletons in Angular. Lazy loaded modules will create all new services that it imports. That's why you have to define a service module, and only import that module into your main module.

Answer (score 1):

Services are singleton if they are injected at the root level that is on the module level but if you injected the service inside a component it creates a new instamce of the service for that particular component.

If you declare you service at module level it will be singleton and you can use it for sharing data

Does that answer you question ?

Comment: you answers its not related to what i asked. if that possible i would be haapy to see code example . thanks for the help